# Finding a difference in time in minutes for values in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I want to do here is to find the time difference between `StatusID = 'Processed'` and `StatusID = 'NEW'` according to its owner ID. and after getting the difference for each owner ID, I want to find the maximum, minimum and average time difference. This is the sample data for it.

| OWNER_ID | CREATED_TIME | STATUS_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-07-16 08:29:29.000 | NEW |
| 1 | 2022-02-21 04:38:01.000 | PROCESSED |
| 3 | 2022-02-28 14:24:28.000 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-02-28 14:27:32.000 | CONVERTED |
| 4 | 2022-02-28 14:33:06.000 | NEW |
| 4 | 2022-02-28 14:33:19.000 | IN_PROCESS |
| 5 | 2022-03-01 12:01:48.000 | NEW |
| 5 | 2022-03-01 12:02:00.000 | IN_PROCESS |

I have tried out this code to get the time difference but my code is not working.

```
SELECT 
    OWNER_ID, 
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, (SELECT CREATED_TIME
                      FROM table
                      WHERE STATUS_ID = 'IN_PROCESS'),
                     (SELECT CREATED_TIME
                      FROM table
                      WHERE STATUS_ID = 'NEW'))
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
    OWNER_ID
```

The desired output is in this format and after getting the result, I want to find the maximum, minimum and average time difference.

| OWNER_ID | TIME_DIFFERENCE(in mins) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 |
| 3 | 800 |
| 4 | 1300 |

Comment: Please provide the desired results to match the provided sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression with aggregate

```
SELECT OWNER_ID, 
       DATEDIFF(SECOND,
                MIN (CASE WHEN STATUS_ID = 'NEW' THEN CREATED_TIME END),
                MAX (CASE WHEN STATUS_ID = 'IN_PROCESS' THEN CREATED_TIME END) )
FROM   table
GROUP BY OWNER_ID
```

Comment: thanks alot for the code, can i ask after getting the result, how can i extract the average, max and min along with the owner_ID?

Comment: `average, max and min` of what value ?

Comment: The value of time difference. The code generates a table with two columns with OWNER_ID and TIME_DIFFERENCE. and I do not know how to extract the max, min, avg value from that resulted table.

Comment: You should start a new question on this. Your requirement is now differs from the original  question. Do remember to include more sample data and the expected result in your new question